# Class components referencing and setting their own static variables - what is the functional component equivalent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

When using class components, I am able to set static variables that will persist on each further instance of the class. This allows me to set a kind of `firstRun` state on a component, even when calling the same component multiple times.

I have tried to create this behaviour in a functional component, but when the component is used multiple times, it seems to forget its states, ref, etc each time.

In the code below, I have two components, one functional and one class. Each one of these components is called three times in `App`. In the class component I am able to directly set `ClassComponent.firstRun` which I am then able to reference in further inclusions of the same component. In the functional component I have tried the same with `useRef`, but this only seems to work **per** instance of the component, and gets forgotten on each new component.

```
const { useEffect, useRef } = React;

const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  const { id } = props;
  const mounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      console.log('Initial functional component load...', id);
      mounted.current = true;
    } else {
      console.log('Functional component has already been initialised.', id)
    }
  }, []); 
  return (
    <div>Hello, functional component!</div>
  );
};

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createSomething();
  }
  
  static firstRun = true;
  
  createSomething() {
    if (ClassComponent.firstRun) {
      console.log('Initial class component load...', this.props.id);
      ClassComponent.firstRun = false;
    } else {
      console.log('Class component has already been initialised.', this.props.id);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello, class component!</div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ClassComponent id="class-component-1" />
      <ClassComponent id="class-component-2" />
      <ClassComponent id="class-component-3" />
      <FunctionalComponent id="functional-component-1" />
      <FunctionalComponent id="functional-component-2" />
      <FunctionalComponent id="functional-component-3" />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The class component works good - I get one log for the initial load, then two logs saying it has already intialised - great! The functional component however is logging three initial load messages.

I have tried using `useState`, but as I understand this only works for re-renders, and not separate occurences of the component. This also seems to be the same situation when using `useRef`.

I have read about function closures, and tried to crudely implement one with the code below, but this again is just giving me three `Initialised...` logs:

```
const checkInitial = () => {
  let initial = true; 
  return {
    get: function() { return initial },  
    set: function(state) { initial = state; }
  };
}
...
const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  const { id } = props;
  const mounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const firstRun = checkInitial();
    if (firstRun.get()) {
      console.log('Initial...', id);
      firstRun.set(true);
    } else {
      console.log('Already run...', id);
    }
  }, []); 
  return (
    <div>Hello, functional component!</div>
  );
};
```

I believe that setting a context variable may be able to get around this, but I'd rather not use that right now. I'm also aware that I can lift the state up to the parent, but I want to avoid this as it will most likely cause re-renders.

This situation seems to easy to solve with class components, but these are now obsolete. Is there an easy way to do this purely using functional functions/components?

Cheers!

Comment: You could "lift the state up to the parent" as you suggest but use `useRef` instead of `useState` to avoid rerenders.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any hook, whether `useState` or `useRef`, is per instance of the component.

If you really want a static variable<sup>1</sup>, just do exactly the same as you did with the `class` component - store it on the `function` object itself:

```
function FunctionComponent({ id }) {
  if (FunctionComponent.firstRun) {
    console.log('Initial function component render...', id);
    FunctionComponent.firstRun = false;
  } else {
    console.log('Function component has already been rendered before.', id);
  }
  return (
    <div>Hello, function component!</div>
  );
}
FunctionComponent.firstRun = true;
```

It would be more customary though to just declare a variable in the module scope where the function component is defined:

```
let firstRun = true;
function FunctionComponent({ id }) {
  if (firstRun) {
    console.log('Initial function component render...', id);
    firstRun = false;
  } else {
    console.log('Function component has already been rendered before.', id);
  }
  return (
    <div>Hello, function component!</div>
  );
}
```

If you don't want the log to appear every time the component is rendered, but only once, when it is mounted, you can use an effect or the initialiser of a state:

```
let firstRun = true;
function FunctionComponent({ id }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRun) {
      console.log('Initial function component mount...', id);
      firstRun = false;
    } else {
      console.log('Function component has already been mounted elsewhere.', id);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>Hello, function component!</div>
  );
}
```

```
let firstRun = true;
function FunctionComponent({ id }) {
  const [isFirst] = useState(() => {
    if (firstRun) {
      firstRun = false;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>Hello, {isFirst && 'first'} function component!</div>
  );
}
```

<sub>1: You probably *don't* want a static variable. It's ok for constants, but as soon as you have stateful static variable, it's essentially global state. Avoid that.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that's a lot of useful info! I think I'll declare it in the module scope as this seems to be the most proper way to do it. On storing vars on functions/global states, are there any particular reasons why this should be avoided?

Comment: Depends on whom you ask whether it's "acceptable" :-) It's useful if you want anyone who has a reference to the function get access to the static variable, using it as a namespace. It was a popular way to avoid extra global variables without using a module pattern.